# Issue installing zxing on xCode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

I recently tried installing zxing in xCode 4.2 for my next app. Here is what happened.

- I began following the steps, everything was going ok, the first strange thing I noticed is that libZXingWidget.a library showed up red when I added it. I started to get worried because xCode still baffles me. The rest of the steps were followed without issue until I added paths to the header search paths. I tried using an absolute path from /Users to the /cpp/core/src/ and /iphone/ZXingWidget/Classes directories I set up then a relative path and no matter what I get the following error:

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/myusername/Desktop/../../cpp/core/src/zxing/common/GreyscaleLuminanceSource.cpp'

Which .cpp file is causing this seems to rotate around. Funny thing is that do not ever even specify Desktop in my header search paths. Early on I had my folders on my desktop and I was referencing them from there but since then I have deleted that project and have a completely new one. I have no idea what is causing the project to search that location and I would like to know how I can change it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting then re-adding the lib. If the problem still occurs, you may want to look into the pbxproj xml file with a text editor to try to see where the wrong path come from.

Comment: Thanks guys. I got it fixed, it was a problem with my paths. I was able to find the pbxproj file helpful in solving this.

Comment: @GregPrice how you solve this problem what path u gave i have the same issue can u please share that given path?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Try to move your "cpp" folder to "Users", if it helps then you have problems with your pathes.